# Gridstack "Pin" items

Tags: jquery, gridstack

I have implemented Gridstack, but I can't figure out how can I make items Stick.

Pin items when clicked i.e they move to top and can't be moved or drag. 
More items can be pinned, they will flow from left to right, top to bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Per the docs,you can call `grid.movable` with the element you want to pin and a `false` parameter.

> movable(el, val) Enables/Disables moving.
>
> el - widget to modify val - if true widget will be draggable.

https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js/tree/develop/doc#movableel-val